# Strange behavior of FragmentManager.findFragmentByTag()

Tags: android, android-fragments

Ok, today I noticed a strange behavior of findFragmentByTag(): if I rotate the screen one time the fragment is returned correctly, but on second rotation I always get null. Am I Doing something wrong? is there a way to fix this?

```
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment f = fm.findFragmentByTag("frag");
        if (f == null){
            Log.e("Fragment","null");
            f = new Fragment();
        }
        f.setRetainInstance(true);
        fm.beginTransaction().remove(f).add(f, "frag").commit();

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to call `setRetainInstance(true);` in fragment's `onCreate()` and change the code above to:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (savedInstance == null){
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment f = new Fragment();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(f, "frag").commit();
    }
}
```

Set the id as well to show it in a layout view group

Comment: thank you, your answer got my to the solution, since I need to call some methods on the Fragment i need it to be "retrieved" via a findFragmentByTag. It seems like that if you remove and readd a Fragment it's tag will not be set for some reason.

Comment: Glad I could help ... Don't forget to upvote and accept answer. ;)